# Getting Error while installing dlib (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, pip, dlib

I have already installed VS and CMake but still, I am unable to install dlib.

Following error triggers while executing the command on CMD (***pip install dlib***) I have tried two versions, dlib and dlib==19.18.0.
I have tried many different solutions but still stuck, also tried to uninstall everything including VS and reinstalling it but this didn't help me.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>pip install dlib==19.18.0
Collecting dlib==19.18.0
  Using cached dlib-19.18.0.tar.gz (3.1 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y57adt7m\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y57adt7m\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5k984utj'
       cwd: C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\
  Complete output (84 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
    Failed to run MSBuild command:

      C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe

    to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

      Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework
      Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

      Build started 22/07/2020 10:00:29 am.
      Project "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
      PrepareForBuild:
        Creating directory "x64\Debug\".
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(475,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
        Creating directory "x64\Debug\VCTargetsPath.tlog\".
      InitializeBuildStatus:
        Creating "x64\Debug\VCTargetsPath.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" is invalid. [C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
      Done Building Project "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

      Build FAILED.

      "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
      (PrepareForBuild target) ->
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(475,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]


      "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
      (PostBuildEvent target) ->
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" is invalid. [C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

          1 Warning(s)
          1 Error(s)

      Time Elapsed 00:00:00.65


    Exit code: 1



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/NOUMAN/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-y57adt7m/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y57adt7m\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y57adt7m\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y57adt7m\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y57adt7m\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y57adt7m\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fa__5h9h\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\
    Complete output (86 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      Failed to run MSBuild command:

        C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe

      to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

        Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework
        Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

        Build started 22/07/2020 10:00:33 am.
        Project "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
        PrepareForBuild:
          Creating directory "x64\Debug\".
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(475,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
          Creating directory "x64\Debug\VCTargetsPath.tlog\".
        InitializeBuildStatus:
          Creating "x64\Debug\VCTargetsPath.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" is invalid. [C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
        Done Building Project "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

        Build FAILED.

        "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
        (PrepareForBuild target) ->
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(475,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]


        "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
        (PostBuildEvent target) ->
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" is invalid. [C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

            1 Warning(s)
            1 Error(s)

        Time Elapsed 00:00:00.65


      Exit code: 1



    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/NOUMAN/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-y57adt7m/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y57adt7m\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y57adt7m\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y57adt7m\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y57adt7m\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y57adt7m\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NOUMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y57adt7m\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NOUMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fa__5h9h\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\NOUMAN\anaconda3\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The error message is `The specified task executable location "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" is invalid.`. Do you have a file referenced in this message?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I don't have the file I checked it in the temp folder.